# Why model.fit calls __getitem__ (no_steps_in_epoch + 1) times inside a single epoch?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I would like to understand why when I call model.fit with a custom data generator the method __getitem__ is called (DataGenerator.__len__() + 1) times instead of DataGenerator.__len__() times, where, from my understanding, DataGenerator.__len()__ represents the number of steps in a single epoch.

In my real code, I have a method (__data_generation()) that works on the assumption that every epoch the __getitem__ is called exactly *no_steps_in_a_epoch* times (it does not use the batch index for several reasons...)

```
import tensorflow.keras as keras
import numpy as np
class DataGenerator(keras.utils.Sequence):
    def __init__(self):
        self.counter = 0

    def __len__(self):
        "Denotes the number of batches per epoch"
        return 10

    def __getitem__(self, batch_index):
        "Generate one batch of data"
        self.counter += 1
        print("step:", self.counter, "batch index:", batch_index)
        return np.array([[1,2,3],[2,3,4]]), np.array([[1],[1]])
        # return self.__data_generation()

    # something else ...

# main
generator = DataGenerator()
model = keras.Sequential()
model.add(keras.layers.InputLayer(input_shape=(3,)))
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(2, activation="relu"))
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(1, activation="relu"))
model.compile(optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam(), loss=keras.losses.MeanAbsoluteError())
model.fit(x=generator, epochs=1)
```

The console output

```
2021-06-04 15:51:53.799143: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:64] Could not load dynamic library 'cudart64_110.dll'; dlerror: cudart64_110.dll not found
2021-06-04 15:51:53.799623: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cudart_stub.cc:29] Ignore above cudart dlerror if you do not have a GPU set up on your machine.
2021-06-04 15:51:58.849246: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:64] Could not load dynamic library 'nvcuda.dll'; dlerror: nvcuda.dll not found
2021-06-04 15:51:58.849511: W tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_driver.cc:326] failed call to cuInit: UNKNOWN ERROR (303)
2021-06-04 15:51:58.868907: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_diagnostics.cc:169] retrieving CUDA diagnostic information for host: <FOOOOOOOOO>
2021-06-04 15:51:58.869366: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_diagnostics.cc:176] hostname: <FOOOOOOOOO>
2021-06-04 15:51:58.870424: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:142] This TensorFlow binary is optimized with oneAPI Deep Neural Network Library (oneDNN) to use the following CPU instructions in performance-critical operations:  AVX AVX2
To enable them in other operations, rebuild TensorFlow with the appropriate compiler flags.
step: 1 batch index: 0
2021-06-04 15:51:59.016093: I tensorflow/compiler/mlir/mlir_graph_optimization_pass.cc:176] None of the MLIR Optimization Passes are enabled (registered 2)
step: 2 batch index: 2
step: 3 batch index: 5
 1/10 [==>...........................] - ETA: 6s - loss: 0.9147step: 4 batch index: 7
step: 5 batch index: 3
step: 6 batch index: 0
step: 7 batch index: 1
step: 8 batch index: 8
step: 9 batch index: 4
step: 10 batch index: 6
step: 11 batch index: 9
10/10 [==============================] - 1s 2ms/step - loss: 0.9001
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that "the plus one"  is related to an operation named TRACING https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/function#tracing, TensorFlow uses tracing to build the graph whenever is necessary. The method Model.fit() build a graph before training, and the first loop of the model is just used to construct the graph, and then the model starts to loop on the whole dataset or data generator.